# Leaderboard component of the community

Tags: apex, community, profile, single-sign-on

The Reputation Leaderboard component populates for users when they go to community without logging in.

But when they login all entries from the Reputation Leaderboard component disappear. When the user tries to login through internal salesforce with system admin profile it works fine but not for other profile.

Is the leader board component is working as designed or there is some permission or profile related issue responsible.

Comment: Were you able to find a resolution to this? We're experiencing a similar issue. Internal users can see the full list of 10 on Leaderboard though our external profiles aren't able to see each other. They can see each other's Chatter posts, just no Leaderboard. Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reputation Leaderboard is intended to display information about other Community Members, it stands to reason that logged in users need to have access to those members. We have checked the org-wide default Sharing Settings and see that the Default External Access level for Users is set to Private.

There is a section on that page under User Visibility Settings that has an option called "Community User Visibility", which is currently unchecked. This setting ensures Community Members can see one another, regardless of org-wide defaults.

You may enable "Community User Visibility" under User Visibility Settings

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like leaderboard component is available only for Napili template and not for others** .

Here is the reference from the release notes

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rss_component_reference_table.htm

Hopefully you are not using Napili and may be causing issue

Comment: But it works during logout state when directly go to homescreen , But when customer login it disappear.  It works fine when logged in internally through salesforce with system admin profile but not when logged in with any other user